# linux terminal based desktop

Tags: linux, terminal, desktop

does anybody know, if there is a desktop environment for linux-distros, that is completely based on terminals, but still is able to let the commands create windows (e.g. a browser, an email-program, multimedia, ...)?

Background is, that i want to use my old laptop again - but he is pretty slow and every little performance-saver would help a lot. Also i don't need much besides the terminal, email und a browser.

My research only brought up solutions, where the basic desktop-environment still runs in the background and though still uses system capacity.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest that if you are concerned about the hardware capability. You can try to install a ubuntu linux live on a usb and let that system be your bootable part and mount the internal hdd to your system.

Comment: [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) or [openbox](http://openbox.org/) ?

Comment: This question doesn't belongs to SO, but i'd suggest to install eg. base Debian distribution, install Xorg and minimalist window manager, eg. wmii, dwm, xmonad, openbox, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read about fvwm2. I also used it ( though it needs Xorg if I remember correctly ). Very minimalistic.
http://www.fvwm.org/

Comment: fvwm2 is exactly what i was searching for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must choose if you want a pure terminal (No X Server) and use apps like [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/) for email and [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/) for websurfing, or if you want a light desktop environment like [openbox](http://openbox.org/), [i3wm](http://i3wm.org/), [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/)...

You should look at [MiniLinux distros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MiniLinux), like [DSL](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/), or [SliTaz](http://www.slitaz.org/)

I have an old laptop which runs smoothly with SliTaz, but try and find which is best for you.